# No such property: variantManager

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ble-plx

I have an issue on the compilation on **vs code** and on **android studio**:

The build view:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-ble-plx'.
> No such property: variantManager for class: com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
```

Thanks for your help :)

```
Android Gradle Pugin Version : 3.6.1
Gradle Version 5.6.4
```

Comment: have you installed & link ```react-native-ble-plx```?

Comment: thank you for your answer, but yes it is installed and link `info iOS module "react-native-ble-plx" is already linked
info Android module "react-native-ble-plx" is already linked`

Answer (score 1):

Everything points to the gradle version.

I was using gradle `5.4.1` and everything was working good until I updated to `5.6.4`. So downgrading seems to be the only solution ATM (as also indicated here https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues/630)